# C++ template inheritance visibility lost in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am struggling with a very simple template design:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    int i=4;
};

template <typename T>
class B : public  A<T> {
public:
    int f() {return i;}
};
```

The compiler says that i is not declared in the scope of B. I can solve it by prefixing with A:

```
int f() {return A<T>::i;}
```

But, as this is an extract of a more general design, I want to understand the problem: `B<T>` has `A<T>` as a father so i should be accessible without prefixing?

I think it must be a trivial problem but I can't see the solution.

Comment: `this->i` would be enough

Comment: Yes but it doesn't explain why it is impossible to access i directly.

Comment: No, I was searching for the duplicate question with answers that _does_ explain it - but Brian found it first. Just read the answers in that link and it should be explained.